# Build iOS and Android ARToolkit wrappers (ARWrapper) libraries for Unity 3D

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, build, artoolkit

I have been trying for a while to figure out how to build the ARWrapper library that is used by Unity to interface to ARToolkit 5.3.1. I can build the ARWrapper bundle using the ARToolkit source but I have no idea how to move from the bundle to the platform specific libraries (iOS and Android). In ARToolkit package for Unity there are the following assets provided which I need to build:

> Android: AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.meta, BT200Ctrl.jar,
>   BT200Ctrl.jar.meta, libARWrapper.so, libARWrapper.so.meta,
>   libc++_shared.so, libc++_shared.so.meta, res: res.meta, UnityARPlayer.jar,
>   UnityARPlayer.jar.meta
>
> iOS: ARToolKitUtilities.m, ARToolKitUtilities.m.meta, libARWrapper.a,
>   libARWrapper.a.meta, libjpeg.a, libjpeg.a.meta

But so far using ARToolkit source code I could only build one bundle file (ARWrapper.bundle).

Could someone please help me understand how to move from the bundle to platform specific libraries as shown above in the asset folder of the package. More specifically I want to be able to build libARWrapper.so and libARWrapper.a

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There is a ARToolKit official Unity plugin, as well as Android and iOS. Sounds to me that you're trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I want to modify the wrapper and add a few timers for performance measurement. Once I'm done modifying the wrapper I want to build it and test the results on Android and iOS mobile phones.

Comment: why don't you do that outside the wrapper, in a Unity class? Sounds like it would save you a lot of headaches

Comment: I think for simplicity the wrapper combined multiple functions into two calls (arwCapture and arwUpdateAR), but I want to measure the performance of each step inside those functions, such as marker detection, tracking, matching etc. That is possible only if I change the code inside the wrapper.

Comment: What about using CMake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libARWrapper is part of ARToolKit for each platform.

- You already built it for OS X, presumably using the ARToolKit for OS X SDK.
- To build it for iOS, you'll need to download the ARToolKit for iOS SDK and build in Xcode, then copy libARWrapper.a from libs into your Unity project.
- For Android, again, download the ARToolKit for Android SDK, open a terminal window, `cd android` and then `./build.sh`. Finally, copy the libARWrapper.so from the libs directory into your Unity project.
- For Windows Win32, download ARToolKit for Windows SDK, do build, copy ARWrapper.dll from the bin directory into your Unity project.

The other portions you mentioned can generally be rebuilt on each platform. For Android, the other key component you might want to rebuild is UnityARWrapper.jar, the source for which is included in the ARToolKit for Unity SDK.

Comment: That's correct! Turned out I need to checkout the complete project from their github to be able to do this without any issues. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the good toolchain I guess you should use CMake
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling

Basically the idea is to get the source code, create a build directory and then:

```
cd build
~/src/build$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/Toolchain.cmake ..
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't have the toolchain profile nor CMake. To me it looks like the developers of the ARToolkit used gradle for the build but I can't figure out how.